# Salesforce sync with Pardot

Tags: pardot

Current setup is pushing contacts in salesforce to Pardot. There is an issue where all contacts are not pushed to Pardot, Is there any filter settings that I can look into to see why only some contacts are pushed to pardot? The Connector in Pardot is configured to sync all leads and contacts created in salesforce and assign to a particular campaign. any help here is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it syncing only new contacts but not historical? Once you integrate the connectors, only new contacts from that point forward will be sync's. Historical records won't sync until a change is made to the contact record in SF

Answer (score 0):

The connector does not apply filters but limits sync to Leads and Contacts only that meet requirements:

> Pardot creates a prospect when a lead or contact with an email address
>   that is not already associated with a prospect is created in
>   Salesforce. An email address is required on the lead or contact record
>   to sync to Pardot. This setting is not retroactive and creates
>   prospects only for those leads and contacts created after this setting
>   has been enabled.

[Info on Salesforce help.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_sf_connector_settings_reference.htm)